# How can I use another view if a specific parameter is given?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have an action called `new`:

```
  def new
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.mobile
      format.xml  { render :xml => @bookmark }
    end
  end
```

Now, when the `param[:widget] == "true"`, I want to use a lay-out other than `application.html.haml`, and I want to show another view than `new.html.haml` called `new_widget.html.haml`.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def new
  @bookmark = Bookmark.new

  if params[:widget] == "true"
    render 'new_widget.html.haml', :layout => 'path/to/other/layout'
    return
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.mobile
    format.xml  { render :xml => @bookmark }
  end
end
```